# Add unique completion handler to every WKWebView load

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have code that loads several web-pages using `WKWebView`. Is there a way to attach a unique completion handler function to each `WKWebView.loadHTMLString` call.

I noticed each returns [`WKNavigation?`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigation), but I don't want to use `WKNavigationDelegate` as this is for all loading events.

By example, right now without a completion handler, I do this:

```
wkWebView?.loadHTMLString("<p>Loading page #1</p>", baseURL: nil)
```

I would like a unique completion handler like this:

```
wkWebView?.loadHTMLString("<p>SLoading page #1</p>", baseURL: nil, completionHandler: {
    print("Loaded page #1. Doing things only required for page #1.")
})
```

Then for a different load I could change the completion handler:

```
wkWebView?.loadHTMLString("<p>SLoading page #2</p>", baseURL: nil, completionHandler: {
    print("Loaded page #2")
})
```

Comment: @matt I can't use `WKNavigation` as it's for all navigation events delegated to a single object (if I'm understanding the purpose of it). I have multiple objects that need to load a HTML string, then perform some action.  Something akin to [evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript), but for loading HTML is what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: But isn't that just a matter of routing messages intelligently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you yourself rightly say, `loadString` returns a WKNavigation object *for exactly this purpose*. So simply make yourself a dictionary that associates that WKNavigation object with a completion handler, which you store when you are called:

```
var navs = [WKNavigation : () -> ()]()
func loadString(_ s:String, completionHandler:@escaping ()->()) {
    if let nav = wkWebView?.loadHTMLString(s, baseURL:nil) {
        self.navs[nav] = completionHandler
    }
}
```

Now, acting as the WKWebView's `navigationDelegate`, when you hear that a page has loaded, you call its corresponding completion handler:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if let f = self.navs[navigation] {
        f()
    }
}
```